# How to build a DataFrame with an indexed dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I use a DF of numbers (which are Y) with an index of 'Names' and columns of 'Date' and compute a PLS regression on 3 other variables (X) not in the DF. 
I want to extract the beta 'o' for each names at each dates of this DF, which are computed with a loop indexed on dates.
The problem is that there are a lot of missing data (Y) because all names are not present at each dates.
So, I built an indexed dictionary o[i] with all the names existing at a particular dates, and so on..
my question is : How to built a DF with the betas with the dates and the names as columns and index ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Results of the PLS can be organised like below :

```
o={}
o[0]={'Date' : '1995-12-12', 'Names' : ['Jack','Jeff','Paul'] ,'Beta' : [0.254,0.12,0.35]}
o[1]={'Date' : '1995-12-13', 'Names' : ['Jack','Jeff','Paul'], 'Beta' : [0.21,0.11,0.31]}
o[2]={'Date' : '1995-12-14', 'Names' : ['Jack','Jeff','Paul','Olivia'], 'Beta' : [0.1,0.08,0.4,0.15]}
o[3]={'Date' : '1995-12-15', 'Names' : ['Jack','Jeff','Paul','Olivia'], 'Beta' : [0.2,0.13,0.37,0.09]}
o[4]={'Date' : '1995-12-16', 'Names' : ['Jeff','Paul','Olivia','Stef'], 'Beta' : [0.15,0.29,0.33,-0.01]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and do it the following way:

```
# Create the dataframe
df = pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, o.values())))

# Reindex by Date and Names
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Names'])
```

resulting in

```
                    Beta
Date       Names        
1995-12-12 Jack    0.254
           Jeff    0.120
           Paul    0.350
1995-12-13 Jack    0.210
           Jeff    0.110
           Paul    0.310
1995-12-14 Jack    0.100
           Jeff    0.080
           Paul    0.400
           Olivia  0.150
1995-12-15 Jack    0.200
           Jeff    0.130
           Paul    0.370
           Olivia  0.090
1995-12-16 Jeff    0.150
           Paul    0.290
           Olivia  0.330
           Stef   -0.010
```